# Save ArrayList or LinkedList is faster in JPA?

Tags: java, arrays, jpa, arraylist, linked-list

`LinkedList` is faster in add element. But `ArrayList` is better in stored data.

I suppose that I will have 1 million elements to add to the List. Then I will use method `saveAll()` to save them in DB. Code like below:

```
//ArrayList
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
fullPersonList.forEach(item -> {
    if (item.isMale())
        personList.add(item);
});
personRepository.saveAll(personList);

//LinkedList
List<Person> personList = new LinkedList<>();
fullPersonList.forEach(item -> {
    if (item.isMale())
        personList.add(item);
});
personRepository.saveAll(personList);
```

Comment: Faster in which aspect, adding elements to the list, or the subsequent iteration of the list?

Comment: They way you use them, they would perform the same.

Comment: JPA tends to write to databases and thus to disks. The performance of *that* write will severely outweigh any performance difference you could have between `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`, so forget about it. Also: forget about `LinkedList´, there's no good reason to ever use it.  [Even the creator agrees](https://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/583813919019573248).

Comment: There are complicated secondary effects due to garbage collection and memory locality which will affect `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` differently.   Especially for large lists.  Also, if you can set the correct *capacity* of the `ArrayList` it will be a lot more efficient than a `LinkedList`; i.e. "LinkedList is faster in add element" won't be true.

Comment: Frankly, this question has the whiff of *premature optimization*.

Comment: As a basic rule of thumb, in almost all cases, ArrayList is actually faster than LinkedList, so use ArrayList, unless you have proven that LinkedList is faster for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better seeing the definition of `personRepository.saveAll(personList)`

Regardless, ArrayList internally uses an array. I expect a read operation to be hence faster, so I'd go with the ArrayList

see [linked_list_implementation here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-a-linked-list-in-java-using-class/)